# How extract a child class and all its child class from a list?

Tags: c#

and sorry for the weird title.

There is my class hierarchy :

- `TimedObject`

  - `SpeedModifer`

    - `ImediateSpeedModifier`
    - `LinearSeedModifier`
    - .. More classes ..
  - .. More classes ..

In the files, all TimedObject's instances are in the same array (so, a `List<TimedObject>`). I want, after the data are loaded, I want to move every SpeedModifier or child class to another array for performance issue. I already know the `Enumerable.OfType<T>()` function, but is this function works in my case ? So, will it work for `ImediateSpeedModifier`, and other `SpeedModifier` ?

If not, what do I need to do for my case ?

Thanks you for yours answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work, since an object of type `ImmediateSpeedModifier` *is a* `SpeedModifier`.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) confirms this (emphasis mine):

> The `OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable)` method returns only those elements in source that **can be cast** to type `TResult`.

There are very few methods in the .NET framework which check for the *exact* dynamic type, since the ability of subtypes to be used in place of theirs supertypes is a [fundamental principle of object-oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860/87698). Checking for the *exact* type is only needed in exceptional circumstances (e.g. [unit testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx)).

Comment: I haven't seen this in the documentation, thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.OfType<T>()` will work. So:

```
var list = new List<TimedObject>();
//load data into list
var filteredList = list.OfType<SpeedModifer>();
```